# How can I tell if a website is using a Hybrid Web Design approach?

Tags: mobile, web, responsive-design

Based from what I've read, there are 2 common types of Website Design: [responsive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Responsive_design) and [separate desktop & mobile sites](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Mobile/Separate_sites).   Then, there's the [hybrid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Mobile/A_hybrid_approach) that combines the two.

It's easy to distinguish a responsive website by resizing the browser.  A website that uses "separate desktop/mobile approach" can be distinguished easily if the user is redirected to another site, similar to Facebook that redirects the user to "m.facebook.com".

Now what confuses me is identifying a hybrid website.  How can one tell that the website is Hybrid?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.
I think there is an easy way to find it out.

- First compare websites on mobile and on browser, but make browser window same size as phone (around 350px width). If websites look same - most likely it's responsive. If you see some difference - it could be separate or hybrid.
- Next find and open css file of the website (or all of them) and see if you could find any @media rules here. If you see some - it means that website do have responsive technique also and you meet the hybrid. If you don't see any sign of @media - you're visiting the separate made website.

Maybe I could answer better with having the link or more details